# How to declare identifier with internal-linkage in block-scope without prior declaration of that identifier with some linkage being visible?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, linkage

Consider this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int b;

int main()
{
    {
        int b;

        {
            extern int b;

            b = 2;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", b);
}
```

Here by definition the identifier 'b' which is assigned the value 2 must have be the one with external linkage. However for some reason the 'clang' C compiler doesn't complain and the output of this code is '2'.

I'm assuming this because of $6.2.2.4 point in the C standard:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in
>   a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31)
>   if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the
>   linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the
>   linkage specified at the prior declaration. **If no prior declaration is
>   visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the
>   identifier has external linkage**.

And as the previous visible declaration specifies no linkage ('int b').

Anyhow how can I make the declaration before the assignment to refer to the identifier with internal linkage (instead of the one with external such).

Edit: I see that this example is UB but this doesn't change my question.

Comment: May I ask what was that down-vote for?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can't have an identifier with both internal and external linkage at the same scope.

[*C11, §6.2.3, 4*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p7) says

> If, within a translation unit, the same identfier appears with both
>   internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So how can it not be one?

Comment: They *can't* be one. Having both internal *and* external linkage for the same identifier doesn't make sense (standard says it's undefined). `int b;`(within the outer block inside `main()`) has no linkage. `extern int b;` declares `b` with external linkage which conflicts with `static int b;` which specifies internal linkage.

Comment: No I meant how can my example program doesn't produce UB without removing the variable without linkage. You are not answering my question.

Comment: Can you elaborate this "No I meant how can my example program doesn't produce UB without removing the variable without linkage"?

Comment: Just answer my question in the OP.

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve. One way to access the varaible with internal linkage is to use a pointer to it: `static int b; int *p = &b;` and then use `p` to read/write the variable with internal linkage. With this, you can have another `b` with *no linkage*.
Other than that I don't see any way to access the `static int b;` in the way you want.